# control swipe item velocity with ItemTouchHelper in recyclerview

Tags: android, swipe

I tried to implement swipe gesture on recyclerview items using itemTouchHelper, but the default speed of swipe is very fast, I need this a little bit slower. How can i control the swipe speed ?

With RecyclerView ItemTouchHelper i'm trying to implement spring type behaviour for recyclerview list items, as i want to build a feature "swipe to reply" for my app, but the swipe velocity provided by itemTouchHelper is very fast, this does not good for user experience, so is there any way or work around to reduce swipe velocity in itemTouchHelper class ?

Answer (score 0):

I came across your message while working on a similar feature. If you're still looking for a solution, here's what might help:

Simply divide the horizontal displacement caused by the user's action. In my case, dividing by 10 worked well. You can adjust this value based on your needs.

```
val swipeHelper =
    ItemTouchHelper(
        object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            ) = true

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {}

            override fun onChildDraw(
                canvas: Canvas,
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                dX: Float,
                dY: Float,
                actionState: Int,
                isCurrentlyActive: Boolean,
            ) {
                super.onChildDraw(
                    canvas,
                    recyclerView,
                    viewHolder,
                    dX / 10,
                    dY,
                    actionState,
                    isCurrentlyActive
                )
            }
        }
    )
swipeHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rvList)
```